# blank plot of array with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am tinkering around with a multi-output machine learning problem that outputs an array, why wont this plot? matplotlib just shows me a blank plot...  Thanks for any tips

What is shown if it makes a difference is my data is `, dtype=float32`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

arr2 = ([[0.68923926, 0.24089244, 5.7309055 , 5.577871  , 6.3931932 ,
        5.2483587 , 1.9924439 , 7.486565  , 4.967933  , 7.738652  ,
        4.3851805 , 8.475717  , 4.4674554 , 6.0132623 , 6.9747496 ,
        2.3741233 , 2.408701  , 2.114421  , 3.6028085 , 8.069426  ,
        4.0510483 , 1.4063461 , 1.205783  , 1.4228263 ]])

plt.plot(arr2)
plt.show()
```

screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data looks like a `2D` array of shape `1xn`. Do you mean:

```
plt.plot(arr2[0])
# or just
# plt.plot(arr[0])
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Yep that did it. thank you. Newbie question what is `2D of shape 1xn`?

Comment: I mean a 2-dimensional array with 1 row.